# How can I search for all sweepers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm looking for a search that captures all sweepers on Scryfall. Simply "Destroy all creatures" misses sweepers such as:

- [Languish](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Languish) (gives creatures -x/-x)
- [Farewell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Farewell) (exiles)
- [Terminus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Terminus) (puts on bottom of library)
- [Oblivion Stone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Oblivion%20Stone) (destroys permanents that don't meet a particular condition)
- [Hour of Revelation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hour%20of%20Revelation) (destroys all nonland permanents)

I'm especially interested in sweepers that can kill planeswalkers.

Comment: How would you define "sweeper"?

Comment: @PhilipKendall stuff that all creatures, plus possibly other types of permanents as well.

Comment: Sorry, I can't parse "stuff that all creatures".  Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @PhilipKendall sorry, missing a word. "Stuff that kills all creatures".

Comment: I know I'm being pedantic here, but what is "killing" _in specific MtG rules terms_? Terminus, for instance, will not trigger any "when this creature dies" effects and does not put anything in the graveyard.

Comment: @PhilipKendall "gets this permanent off the battlefield into a zone that is not the hand"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use [Scryfall Tagger](https://tagger.scryfall.com/). The tags are manually applied, so they may be incomplete or inaccurate, but they are useful for vague concepts like this. In particular, the tags [`sweeper-creature`](https://tagger.scryfall.com/tags/card/sweeper-creature), [`sweeper-planeswalker`](https://tagger.scryfall.com/tags/card/sweeper-planeswalker), and [`sweeper-permanent`](https://tagger.scryfall.com/tags/card/sweeper-permanent) are relevant to your question.

Comment: just to add: there is also a tag for all of these, the tag "sweeper" by itself: https://tagger.scryfall.com/tags/card/sweeper

Answer (score 3):

This Scryfall search doesn't narrow it down completely, but it has a lot more hits than misses:

> [`o:/(?<!for |on |tap |goad )\b(all|each)(?! damage)(\s\w+)+ (permanent|creature|planeswalker)s?\b(?! you control| card| gain| have| type| able)/`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2F%28%3F%3C%21for+%7Con+%7Ctap+%7Cgoad+%29%5Cb%28all%7Ceach%29%28%3F%21+damage%29%28%5Cs%5Cw%2B%29%2B+%28permanent%7Ccreature%7Cplaneswalker%29s%3F%5Cb%28%3F%21+you+control%7C+card%7C+gain%7C+have%7C+type%7C+able%29%2F)

The idea is to broadly look for phrases like "all creatures", "each planeswalker", etc., possibly with words in between, with a number of specific words excluded because they appeared on non-removal effects. There's definitely room for further refinement, and some of the exclusions may actually be excluding relevant cards.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `game:paper` to weed out the MTGA specific cards like Divine Purge